# Android Room notNull field is expecting a null default value

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

i'm trying to add new attributes to my tables as shown here:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "invoices", indices = [Index(value = [...], unique = true)]
)
data class Invoice(
    ...
    override val created_at: Long = 0,
    override var approved_at: Long? = 0,
) : ICD
```

so i created the following migration:

```
val MIGRATION_3_4 = object: Migration(3, 4) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE invoices ADD COLUMN created_at INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE invoices ADD COLUMN approved_at INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ")
            }
        }
```

but whenever i try to run it says the migration wasnt handled properly and shows this as expected:

```
TableInfo{name='invoices', columns={... ,created_at=Column{name='created_at', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, approved_at=Column{name='approved_at', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, ... }
```

and this as whats found:

```
TableInfo{name='invoices', columns={... ,created_at=Column{name='created_at', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}, approved_at=Column{name='approved_at', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}}, ... }
```

can anyone tell me why is it expecting default value null please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I believe is, you are using Room version greater than `2.2.0`, and version `2.2.0` and above needs default values of the columns to be defined in their respective entity class using `@ColumnInfo(defaultValue="0")`

For your case add `@ColumnInfo(defaultValue="0")` to `created_at` and `approved_at`

```
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue="0")
override val created_at: Long = 0,
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue="0")
override var approved_at: Long? = 0,
```

And change your migration function to this

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE invoices ADD COLUMN created_at INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE invoices ADD COLUMN approved_at INTEGER")
```

If you're using a Room version `2.4.0-alpha01` and higher, you can use `autoMigration`.

For `autoMigration`, add `autoMigrations` annotation to your database

```
@Database(
    entities = [.., .., ..],
    version = 2,
    autoMigrations = [AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2)]
)
abastract class Database: RoomDatabase
```

Comment: i tried this and now im getting the following error "    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE invoices ADD COLUMN created_at INTEGER NOT NULL
"

Comment: adding default 0 to the migration function sql seems to have fixed the issue (with the annotation you mentioned for the entity)

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your suggestion.